# MS Office 2011: Plugging Excel Data Into a Word Document

Tags: ms-office

(Note: I'm am not sure if this question fits in this StackExchange site, so please correct me if it doesn't belong)

To cut my problem short: I'm trying to make a Word document which prints data from a Excel document.  Is it possible to link an Excel and Word document?  Almost like this:

```
Data A(A,1)
Data B(A,2)
etc.
```

I have tried using templates and just simply printing the excel document without the lines, but my "requirements" are too specific and complex.

Comment: On Windows, this is achievable with DDE. I don't know if it's possible on OS X. Though, apparently VBE is working on Office 2011, so possibly programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. I don't know exactly what you are doing, but doing a mail merge should link a Word document to an Excel spreadsheet. Let me know what you are using it for, and I can post further instructions.

Comment: I am trying to create a school phone directory where each student's entry will print as if in a small box (as opposed to in a straight line across the page).  Each entry will include five lines of info taken from Excel.  The directory will be printed in a small booklet format (half an 8.5 x 11) with approx 12 entries/page (If you even need all that information).

Comment: Will this work as a mail merge? If it doesn't, I can figure out how to make it work.